# SQLite compare given string with two columns

Tags: android, mysql

I have this table:

first_name | last_name

```
 abc       def
 aaa       bbb
 ...       ...
```

I want to make a query that will get a string and find

if this string equals (or part of) - "first_name (space) last_name"

for example, a good queries will be:

a

ab

abc d

abc de

aaa bbb

I tried this selection:

```
String selection = "first_name" + " " + "last_name" + " LIKE '" + GIVEN_STRING + "%'";
```

but without luck

how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SELECT (first_name || " " || last_name) AS full_name WHERE full_name LIKE '%blah%'

Comment: how do I convert it to query method: public Cursor query (String table, String[] columns, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)? thanks!

Comment: String [] columns = new String[] { "(first_name || \" \" || last_name) AS full_name" };
String selection = "full_name LIKE '%" + GIVEN_STRING  + "%'";
query(your_table, columns, selection, null, null, null, null);

Comment: swap `"` <> `'`, sqlite does not like `"` for strings.

Comment: I tested this out and both " and ' work so either way seems right. Although I would stick to what @zapl said using ' since that is generally what sqlite uses for strings

Comment: `String [] columns = new String[] { "(coalesce(first_name, '')  || ' ' || coalesce(last_name, '')) AS full_name" };` if `first_name` and/or `last_name` can be `NULL`. Otherwise the whole term may evaluate to null.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the first `%`. Like this:

```
String selection = "first_name" + " " + 
"last_name" + " LIKE '%" + GIVEN_STRING + "%'";
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `OR` keyword to match among both columns

```
String query = String.format("SELECT * FROM %s WHERE %s OR %s LIKE '%%%s%%';",
            "tableName", "first_name", "last_name", "matchString");
```